# How to change variable inside readline function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have following code and I don't know how to change variable x inside the function.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var r1 = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   terminal: false 
});
var x = 1;
r1.on('line', function(inputText) {
    x = 2; // i want to be able to change it here
}
console.log(x); //prints 1 and I want 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable will change - it's just that your function is *asynchronous* - so your log outside the `on('line')` function is executing before the variable assignment.

Comment: Does the on method return a promise? If yes, OP could extend it and change the variable in then callback function. Am I correct?

Comment: In my code im using input data to create object, that i would like to use later. How to ensure that my function execute before I start using the created object? And what would be the best way to do that?